# How to delete Items from Document Library and its folders in my Sub Site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, powershell

I have written a PowerShell to delete the items in a `Document Library` to delete/clean-up the items.I have 3 folders in my `Document Library` and all the items in these 3 folders must also be deleted.But i am stuck at deleting the items within the folders.Also I am facing issue in deleting the items which are CheckedOutBy someone else.I forcibly checkedin by using the $fileitem.CheckIn("checkedin by powershell").But this did not work.I am able to see the item as its.

```
write-output "" | out-file -filepath c:\inventory.txt

Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell

[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity]::RunWithElevatedPrivileges(
{ 
    $siteCollectionURL = "http://srvr1.company.com/sites/TestRC/"
    $siteColl = Get-SPSite $siteCollectionURL
    $doclibs = @("CB")
    $subFolder = @("folder1" , "folder2" ,"folder3" )
    Function GetFiles($Folder)
    { 
        Write-Host "+"$Folder.Name

        #Loop through all subfolders and call the function recursively
        foreach ($subFolder in $Folder.SubFolders)
        {
            if(($subFolder.Name -eq "Public") -Or ($subFolder.Name -eq "folder1") -Or ($subFolder.Name -eq "folder2" ))
            {  
                Write-Host "`t" -NoNewline
                $Files = $subFolder. | where {$_.FileSystemObjectType -eq "File"} # here i am getting null value though items exist
                if($Files -eq $null)
                {
                   Write-Host "+++++ There is no file in this subfolder " + $subFolder.Title
                   Write-Output "+++++ There is no file in this subfolder " +  $subFolder.Title | out-file -filepath c:\inventory.txt -append 
                }
                else 
                {
                    foreach ($file in $Files) 
                    {
                        $itemFile = $file.File
                        if( $itemFile.CheckOutStatus -ne "None" ) 
                        { 
                            $itemFile.CheckIn("Automatic CheckIn.(Administrator)")
                        }

                        Write-Host "+++++ Deleting file " $file.Name
                        Write-Output "+++++ Deleting file " $file.Name | out-file -filepath c:\inventory.txt -append
                        $file.Delete()
                        Write-Host "+++++ Done with Deleting file " $file.Name
                        Write-Output "+++++ Done with Deleting file " $file.Name | out-file -filepath c:\inventory.txt -append
                    }
                }
                GetFiles($Subfolder)
            }
        }
    }
    if($siteColl -ne $null)
    {
        Write-Host "+ Site Collection : " $siteColl.Name
        Write-Output "+ Site Collection : " $siteColl.Name | out-file -filepath c:\inventory.txt -append 
        Write-Host "++ Site Collection : " $siteColl.Url
        foreach($subWeb in $siteColl.AllWebs)
        {
            if($subWeb -ne $null)
            {
                #Print each Subsite
                Write-Host "+++ Sub Web : " $subWeb.Url
                Write-Output "+++ Sub Web : " $subWeb.Url | out-file -filepath c:\inventory.txt -append 

                # $Libraries = $subWeb.Lists | where {$_.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary"}
                foreach ($doclib in $doclibs)
                {
                    $library =  $subWeb.Lists[$doclib]
                    Write-Host "++++ Getng files from library : " $library.Title
                    Write-Output "++++ Getting files from library : " $library.Title | out-file -filepath c:\inventory.txt -append 
                    #$Files = $library.Items | where {$_.FileSystemObjectType -eq "File"}
                    GetFiles($library.RootFolder)
                }
            }
            # Write-host -ForegroundColor Red ("Items to be deleted : " + $subWeb.RecycleBin.Count.toString())
            # Write-Output ("Items to be deleted : " +$subWeb.RecycleBin.Count.toString()) | out-file -filepath c:\inventory.txt -append 
            # $now = Get-Date
            # Write-host -ForegroundColor Red ("Deleting started at " + $now.toString())
            # Write-Output ("Deleting started at " +$now.toString()) | out-file -filepath c:\inventory.txt -append 
            # if ($subWeb.RecycleBin.Count -ne $null) 
            # {
            #    $subWeb.RecycleBin.DeleteAll();
            # }
            # $now = Get-Date
            # write-host -ForegroundColor Red ("Deleting completed at " +$now.toString())
            # Write-Output ("Deleting completed at " +$now.toString()) | out-file -filepath c:\inventory.txt -append 
            $subWeb.Dispose()
        }
        else
        {
            Echo $subWeb  "does not exist"               
        }
    }
    # write-host $siteColl
    # write-host -ForegroundColor Red ("Items to be deleted : " +$siteColl.RecycleBin.Count.toString())
    # Write-Output ("Items to be deleted : " +$siteColl.RecycleBin.Count.toString()) | out-file -filepath c:\inventory.txt -append 
    # $now = Get-Date
    # write-host -ForegroundColor Red ("Deleting started at " +$now.toString())
    # Write-Output ("Deleting started at " +$now.toString()) | out-file -filepath c:\inventory.txt -append 
    # if ($siteColl.RecycleBin.Count -ne 0) {
    #   $siteColl.RecycleBin.DeleteAll();
    # }
});
```

Comment: Post the script you created so far.

Comment: I have updated my post with the function with detailed code,here,though I am having items exist in the folders, i am unable to delete the items.

Comment: Amal, I checked your blog also for the same.

Comment: If the folders are hidden can't we delete the files within those hidden folders? Currently I have hidden the folders within the document library.